# Maven tells me "Fatal error compiling: invalid target release" though java version is correct

Tags: java, maven, raspberry-pi

Either I'm stupid as hell and missing something very obvious, or my Rasberry Pi is doing very weird things. I'm just trying to compile a simple Java Project and Maven keeps telling me `Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 9.0` allthough I have Java 9 installed:

```
pi@Harald:~ $ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 9-Raspbian, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-armhf
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.14.79-v7+", arch: "arm", family: "unix"
```

I also checked the Paths for java and javac, but both seem to be correct aswell:

```
pi@Harald:~ $ java -version
openjdk version "9-Raspbian"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-Raspbian+0-9b181-4bpo9rpt1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 9-Raspbian+0-9b181-4bpo9rpt1, mixed mode)
```

```
pi@Harald:~ $ javac -version
javac 9-Raspbian
```

What am I missing?

[See full error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULigj.png)

Comment: Can you give snippet of your pom.xml? This can help to rule out some obvious things.

Comment: You have to give simply in `<maven.compiler.release>9</maven.compiler.release>` only instead of `9.0` and I would recommend to use a more recent version for JDK9/10/11 for Raspberry ...cause 9 is out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ensure your `JAVA_HOME` is set to JDK 9.
2. Specify `maven-compiler-plugin` source/target/release properties:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.release>9</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>
```

3. Configure `maven-compiler-plugin` and `maven-toolchains-plugin`:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <toolchains>
                    <jdk>
                        <version>1.9</version>
                        <vendor>oracle</vendor>
                    </jdk>
                </toolchains>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>toolchain</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

*Notes:*

- To configure toolchain, create `~/.m2/toolchains.xml` and add following:

```
<toolchains>
    <toolchain>
        <type>jdk</type>
        <provides>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <vendor>oracle</vendor>
        </provides>
        <configuration>
            <jdkHome>/path/to/your/jdk-9</jdkHome>
        </configuration>
    </toolchain>
</toolchains>
```

- To experiment without updating `pom.xml`: First symlink /bin/javac9 to
  /opt/jdk-9/bin/javac and /opt/jdk-9 to JDK 9 version you are
  currently using. Then try this command:

```
mvn -Dmaven.compiler.fork -Dmaven.compiler.executable=javac9 install
```

Comment: Thanks, though I still dont really understand why maven for some reason didnt use jdk9 in the first place, it does compile and run now. Thanks!